# Как найти в тексте слова с нечетным количеством букв и удалить из них среднюю букву?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно на C# с помощью регулярных выражений в введенном тексте найти слова с нечетным количеством букв, а потом удалить из них среднюю букву.

Comment: Что-то так себе идея... Нормальные регулярки так не умеют, впрочем, вероятно, что в шарповских что-то для этого есть.Например, рекурсия.

Comment: @Qwertiy может быть регексами предполагается только искать слова с нечетным количеством букв (это вроде как просто), а удалять среднюю букву - без регексов?

Comment: @PashaPash, возможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy еще есть balancing groups, через которые  парность скобок делают (вроде бы),  можно их попробовать

Comment: @PashaPash, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/4928642 - вот про них. Но я ни разу не пользовался.

Comment: @PashaPash, https://ideone.com/NQEkpf - удаляет последний, а не центральный.

Comment: @PashaPash, получилось :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, это будет проще и понятнее:

```
string input = "aaa bbbb ccccc dddddd";
string pattern = @"\w+";
string RemoveCentralSymbol(string s) => s.Remove(s.Length / 2, s.Length % 2);
var result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, match => RemoveCentralSymbol(match.Value));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Используем перегрузку `Regex.Replace`, принимающую `MatchEvaluator` (делегат, который составит строку для замены)

Answer (score 4):

Удалить среднюю букву из слова с нечётной длиной:

https://ideone.com/k1VQZW

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var text = "123456789";
    var res = Regex.Replace(text, @"^((?<ch>.)*).((?<-ch>.)*(?(ch)(?!))$)", @"$1$2");

    Console.WriteLine(text);
    Console.WriteLine(res);
  }
}
```

Подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/4928642.

Comment: Только надо доработать для поиска отдельных слов :), а не замены в одном слове - \w  порасставлять

Comment: @PashaPash, да, только заметил в вопросе.